# Select td value onClick

Tags: javascript, function, select

I want to select (highlight) the content of second td tags from a table.
Each second td tag have a `onClick` attribute that calls a function.

That function should select td's content.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/RCpKy/1/

In this case the function `selectThis` should select each field `value` by clicking on it.

JS only (no jQuery). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    function selectThis(element) {

    element.style.backgroundColor="#f3f3f3";
}
```

Comment: I don't want to change background color. I want to select the field, with select() function.

Comment: what do u mean by "select the field, with select() function"

Answer (score 0):

`element.textContent` breaks in less han equal to  IE7 ,
`element.innerHTML` works but 
i reccomend using `firstChild.nodeValue`

```
function selectThis(element) {

var selectedTdValue = element.firstChild.nodeValue;

alert(selectedTdValue)
}
```